# Finding density function given a cumulative distribution

Tags: probability

We are given a mixed random varaible $X$ having cumulative distribution

$$ F(x) = \begin{cases} 0 \; \; \; \;\;\;x < 0 \\ \frac{e^x}{e^x+1} \;\;\;\;\;\;\ x \geq 0\end{cases} $$

Obviously, we know $f_X(x) = F'(x) $ Thus

$$ f_X(x) = \frac{ e^x}{(e^x+1)^2 } $$

where $x \geq 0 $ and $0$ otherwise.

However, my answer key gives

$$ f_X(x) = \begin{cases} 1/2 \; \; \; x=0 \\ \frac{ e^x}{(e^x+1)^2 } \; \; \; \; x > 0 \end{cases} $$

Why is there $1/2$ in there? Is it a typo from the book?

Comment: There is a jump in $F$ at $x = 0$.

Comment: the derivative you computed is valid for $x>0$, not for $x\geq 0$.

Comment: I am curious about the $1/2$ at zero as well. My guess is it is convention and it doesn't really matter: we don't care about probabilities of points in the continuous setting

Comment: @qbert Integrating $\frac{\exp(x)}{(\exp(x)+1)^2}$ from $0$ to $+\infty$ only yields $0.5$, so it might have something to do with that (but it is strange...). On closer look, I guess the statement says that the random variable is "mixed".

Comment: @madnessweasley yes, I imagine it's just like defining $H(0)=1/2$ for the Heaviside function, just convention. It's also just the value of $F$ at  0

Comment: actually, if the CDF has a step (of size 1/2), then the slope (i.e. PDF) is infinite there.  I guess technically it should be a Dirac delta...  And @qbert we DO care about probability of points in the continuous setting when the CDF has a step because this means $P(X=0) > 0$, unlike the typical $P(X=x) = 0$ for any single point.  E.g. here $F(0) = P(X \le 0) = 1/2$ while $F(\epsilon) = P(X \le \epsilon) = 0$ for any $\epsilon < 0$, which implies $P(X=0) = 1/2$.  Maybe that's why the book called it "mixed" (of discrete and continuous).

Comment: @antkam right but *why* is it justified to care about the probability at a point? If all the integrals involved are Lebesgue (or at least with respect to measures that are absolutely continuous wrt Lebesgue) then we should not. For example, why set the value of the density here to be 1/2? The derivative of $F$ doesn't exist at 0, and again if these are standard integrals it does not matter what $f_x$ is at $0$ in any integration of $f_x$.

Comment: @qbert - (1) I thought you meant you dont care about $P(X=0)$ because it is 0.  Here it is 1/2.  Sorry if I misunderstood you.  (2) I never said $f_X(0)$ should be 1/2.  It surely should _not_ be 1/2!  If anything I'd put a Dirac delta there so that it _does_ affect integrals.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)  Something like $f_X(x) = \frac{ e^x}{(e^x+1)^2 } \mathbf{1}[x>0] + \frac{1}{2} \delta(x)$.  But that is only acceptable treatment in some circles.  Anyway we can agree the book answer is bogus.

Comment: @antkam oh no, my point was with it being at a point. Yes I could see that interpretation (the weak derivative of the heaviside is a dirac after all).

Comment: @qbert Surely this is my mixed (ha!) engineering+math background talking but I learned that e.g. a fair 6-sided die's PDF is 6 little Dirac deltas each of size 1/6.  :)  Like I said, only acceptable in some circles...  If not that, then $f_X(0)$ here can only be $\infty$ or undefined, but definitely not 1/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that F(0) = 0
F(0+) = 1/(1 + 1) = 1/2   {as e^x when x tend to 0+ is 1}

that means P(X = 0) = F(0+) - F(0) = 1/2

After that it is continuous and f(x) is calculated by taking derivative of cdf.